# VBA find value x in column A and value y in column B and sum values in column C

Tags: excel, vba, multiple-columns

following problem:

Let's say my file looks like this:

```
Column A  | Column B | Column C
ABCDEFI | 7000 | 50 
ABCDEFI | 7500 | 20
ABCDIFE | 7000 | 30
ABCDEFI | 7500 | 80
```

I want to look for "ABCDEFI" in Column A and for "7500" in Column B and sum
up the corresponding values of Column C and store them in Column D.

In this case the end result should be "100" in Column D.

Hope that makes sense.

Happy to see read your answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fairly simple SUMIFS() will work:

```
=SUMIFS(C:C,A:A,"ABCDEFI",B:B,7500)
```